# Does Transform using custom python file work in Spark?

Tags: python, sql, apache-spark, hive, pyspark

Currently, I am processing data in hive using custom mappers and reducers like this:

```
select TRANSFORM(hostname,impressionId) using 'python process_data.py' as a,b from impressions
```

But when I try to apply the same logic in Spark sql, I get `SparkSqlParser` error.
I want to resue the logic in `process_data.py` off the box. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: works for me, using `spark-sql` , at least under Linux (Ubuntu). Doesn't work in Windows though

Answer (score 0):

You need to put in some sort errors stacktrace so that the community can answer your questions quickly. 
For the Python Script to run in your Scala code(that is what i am assuming), you can achieve it in the following way:

**Example** :

**Python File : Code for making Input data to Uppercase**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
for line in sys.stdin:
    print line.upper()
```

**Spark Code : For Piping the data**

```
import org.apaches.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Pipe")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val distScript = "/path/on/driver/PipeScript.py"
val distScriptName = "PipeScript.py"
sc.addFile(distScript)
val ipData = sc.parallelize(List("asd","xyz","zxcz","sdfsfd","Ssdfd","Sdfsf"))
val opData = ipData.pipe(SparkFiles.get(distScriptName))
opData.foreach(println)
```

Comment: Great idea! Did this work for you? The spark code is picking up the python file location from somewhere else.
Cannot run program "/mnt/tmp/spark-e694c253-074d-4893-89a8-9717ef2e6eb8/userFiles-a0bcb586-8aa6-47e2-aa27-d8316764753e/test.py": error=2, No such file or directory.
Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Yes this is what we do for our ETL loads. Does spark have necessary privileges to read from the directory? You can keep the script on hdfs and load it from hdfs itself.

Comment: I have hosted the file in s3.  But it still looking in mnt/tmp location.
/mnt/tmp/spark-33a1d6ad-850c-4d55-8dac-c16077841ef4/userFiles-a3f1ec19-6682-4583-9c1e-7f6cd83ea88e/s3:/move-dataeng-test-dev/temp/test.py": error=2, No such file or directory

Comment: is spark able to read any file from the S3 bucket? this generally happens when the permissions are not assigned correctly to the user that is running the Spark Job

Comment: @SaisumanthGopisetty Can you post your Spark Submit command. This error also takes place when we do not mention the python files to be used  in the JAR under the **--py-files** flag in the **spark-submit** command.

Answer (score 0):

you can create your own custom UDF and can use it within Spark application code. use custom UDF only in case something you can't do with available Spark native functions.

I am not sure what's there in  process_data.py and what kind of input it takes and what are you expecting out of it. 
If it's something that you want to make it available for different application code. you can do as follows:

you can create a class in python and have a function inside it to do processing and add it to your spark application code.

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, args):
    …
    def MyFunction(self):

spark.sparkContext.addPyFile('/py file location/somecode.py')
```

## importing your class in pyspark application code

```
from somecode import MyClass
```

## create an object to access the class and it's function

```
myobject = MyClass()
```

now you can access your class function to send and receive arguments.