# pyspark: no module error when am using a file as module by sending --py-file argument

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark

I have 2 folders named dependencies, src where dependencies folder has 2 python files named `common.py`, `load.py` and src has `driver.py` file.

Now as i want to make common.py, load.py files available to all nodes in the EMR cluster i zipped the dependencies folder to pack.zip and submitted as

```
spark-submit --py-files pack.zip driver.py
```

Note: added **init**.py in the dependencies folder

Issue here is i used common.py/load.py methods inside the driver.py as

```
from dependencies.common import some_function

from dependencies.load import some_function
```

Am getting the No Module error for common/load

I want the expected output without any error the modules common and load has to be loaded in the driver file and utilize them.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's `__init__.py` and it should be in every folder in your python module

Comment: Yes it is available in all the folders from where i wanna use the module, but still the same error. i tried all possible ways.

Comment: Post the structure (directory tree) of your zipped file.

Comment: are you running it in cluster mode? you may also need to add it using addPyfile method to your driver.py. see below https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57665457/does-transform-using-custom-python-file-work-in-spark/57702561#57702561

Comment: yeah running in the cluster mode in aws EMR, now it is giving exit  code13 error.